# How to use PhpUnit/DbUnit with a real Doctrine EntityManager for functional testing

Tags: doctrine-orm, phpunit, entitymanager, functional-testing

I'm using `PhpUnit/DbUnit` to create a set of 5 to 10 fixture records. I use in-memory sqlite.

I successfully can use a `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection` to access it, so I can use methods like `->insert( $tableName, $data );` for my tests.

Now I want to consume the Doctrine `EntityManager` so I can create an entity and call `->persist()`.

In unit-testing I used to mock the `EntityManager` and asserted an expectation to call persist.

But for functional-testing I want to check the final result written to the DB, even go further and re-use the result of the writing.

I therefore need to create a real EntityManager but consuming the DbUnit connection.

I've seen that creting a new `EntityManager` takes 3 arguments, but still the creator is protected:

```
/**
 * Creates a new EntityManager that operates on the given database connection
 * and uses the given Configuration and EventManager implementations.
 *
 * @param \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection     $conn
 * @param \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration   $config
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\EventManager $eventManager
 */
protected function __construct(Connection $conn, Configuration $config, EventManager $eventManager)
{
    [...]
```

I don't know if I'm expected to create a subclass, or maybe use an already subclassed EntityManager or how should I proceed.

## So question:

How can I setup a real `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` within a `PhpUnit/DbUnit` test class using the low level `Doctrine\Dbal\Connection` that is already bound to the `DbUnit` connection?

Note: I'm inside a symfony3 project, so mapping files are in the expected places of symfony.